# linked server set identity_insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to insert from table to another in linked server, need to insert "ID" also in table ,
Can't using identity_insert  on linked server, tried every thing

```
  set identity_insert [10.10.10.10].[POS_KIG].[dbo].[Colors] on
    insert into [10.10.10.10].[POS_KIG].[dbo].[Colors]
    select * from [POS_KIG].[dbo].[Colors] Colors where Colors.ID not In (select HostColor.ID from [10.10.10.10].[POS_KIG].[dbo].[Colors] HostColor)
    set identity_insert [10.10.10.10].[POS_KIG].[dbo].[Colors] off
```

Comment: Note, from the documentation, that [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) only supports up to **3 part** naming. You'll need to instead connect to your instance `10.10.10.10`, and used a linked server connection to the server the data is located on.

Comment: You can't do a linked `IDENTITY_INSERT`. You'll have to remote that code to the server, for example with `EXECUTE ... AT`. Of course you'll also need a way to get the data on your local server to the remote server, either by first inserting to a temp table you create for that purpose, or by allowing a link from the other server to yours instead. Regardless of how you do it, all this is very clunky and you're probably better off considering a different solution altogether, like a one-time export and import from Management Studio, or replication.

Comment: @Larnu Explain more please

Comment: What part didn't you understand, @AbdulrahamanShalata ? I'm not sure what more I can say

Comment: @JeroenMostert the problem here i need to insert from local table

Comment: Yes, your problem is clear, but unfortunately for you, it just can't be done the way you like, so find alternatives. I've supplied all the alternatives I can think of.

Comment: @Larnu  "You'll need to instead connect to your instance 10.10.10.10, and used a linked server connection to the server the data is located on." this part

Comment: You've set up a linked server to `10.10.10.10`; you just need to do the same on *that* server to the server you are connected to.

Comment: @Larnu can't happen because I'm using job in sqlagent so This query can only happen in server

Comment: Then you need to look at a different solution, @AbdulrahamanShalata . The method you are trying cannot happen either. Perhaps you need to use an ETL process of some kind. Clearly there are other constraints/requirements we don't know about here.